# Passing values between MVC Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to pass the values selected from these Radioboxes to the "List" view

cshtml file

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SmokeHouse, 1)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SmokeHouse, 0)

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SmokeCar, 1)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SmokeCar, 0)

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SmokeWork, 1)    
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SmokeWork, 0)

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult SmokingEnvironments()
{
   return View("List");
}
```

class

```
public class Screen
{
    public int SmokeCar { get; set; }
    public int SmokeHouse { get; set; }
    public int SmokeWork { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a submit button that posts to that action, you just need to update your controller to take the model as a parameter and pass it to the next view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult SmokingEnvironments(Screen model)
{
   return View("List", model);
}
```

Comment: what if the view is in a different folder called Results?

Comment: @user2224493 What does that mean?

Comment: return View("~/Views/Results/List.aspx", model);